# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

program doesnt reconize the property name. I use the Input() function and use an API. It should show all tweets from my api. I tried a lot of different thing lik echanging names, properties,... I caan t go on because it doesnt work. Is there an easy way to fix this

tweet.component.html

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>
     {{ tweet.name}}
    </mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>added on {{ tweet.created | date: longDate }}</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
</mat-card>
```

tweet.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Tweet } from '../tweet.model';
import { TweetDataService } from 'src/app/tweet-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tweet',
  templateUrl: './tweet.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tweet.component.css']
})
export class TweetComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public tweet: Tweet;
  constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

tweet.model.ts

```
import { Reactie } from './reactie.model';

export class Tweet{
    constructor(
        private _name: string,
        private _reacties = new Array<Reactie>(),
        private _created = new Date()
      ) {}

      static fromJSON(json: any): Tweet {
        const rec = new Tweet(
          json.text,
          json.reacties,
          json.created
        );
        return rec;
      }
      toJSON(): any {
        return {
          name: this.name,
          reacties: this.reacties.map(re => re.toJSON()),
          created: this.created
        };
      }

      get name(): string {
        return this._name;
      }
      get created(): Date {
        return this._created;
      }
      get reacties(): Reactie[] {
        return this._reacties;
      }
      addReactie(text: string) {
        this._reacties.push(new Reactie(text));
      }


}
```

dataservice

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable, Subject, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Tweet } from './tweet/tweet.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TweetDataService {

  public loadingError$ = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  get recipes$(): Observable<Tweet[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/Tweet/`).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        this.loadingError$.next(error.statusText);
        return of(null);
      }),
      map((list: any[]): Tweet[] => list.map(Tweet.fromJSON))
    );
  }

  addNewTweet(tweet: Tweet) {
    return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/tweets/`, tweet.toJSON());
  }

  getTweet$(id): Observable<Tweet> {
    console.log(`${environment.apiUrl}/tweets/${id}`);
    return this.http
      .get(`${environment.apiUrl}/tweets/${id}`)
      .pipe(map((rec: any): Tweet => Tweet.fromJSON(rec)));
  }
}
```

Comment: check if there is data in your `tweet` object in _tweet.component.html_ by using `console.log()` or `debugger`

Comment: it seems that the template is loaded before data is fetched, try debug to see the value

Comment: And use safe operator {{tweet?.name}} -the "?"-

Comment: I am not seeing you calling `TweetDataService` inside `tweet.component.ts` also you don't have function that return all tweet, you have only `getTweet$(id)` that should take `id` as parameter ?!

Comment: I named something wrong but i don't find the error. getrecipes should be getTweets

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time this issue happened because data sync issue from the service. 
Simple solution to you problem is use the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator) (`?`) like below.

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>
     {{ tweet?.name}}
    </mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>added on {{ tweet?.created | date: longDate }}</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: the error is gone but it doesnt show the data of the API

Comment: it means that the api which you are using doesn't return data

Comment: i Tested it with swagger and their it works and i use the coorect API Call